# How do web.xml filters work? Can you have two filters map to all pages (/*) and specify the order?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security, web.xml

I want to use Spring Security, and it says to map the filter to /***.  But I already have a filter mapped to /*, which is the Tuckee URLRewrite filter.

Is it possible to map two filters to the same thing, and also is there a way to specify the order that the filters get called?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you can:

[The servlet 2.5 xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd):

> The order in which filters are invoked is the order in which filter-mapping declarations that match a request URI for a servlet appear in the list of filter-mapping elements

i.e. it depends on the order of your `<filter-mapping>` elements in the `web.xml`

Comment: Is there no way to do this via annotations ?

Comment: I don't know how is the order determined when using annotations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations