# What will be the order in which filters will be called?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

Suppose I have following in my web.xml

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>F1</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/XYZ/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>F2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/XYZ/abc.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>F3</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

What will be the order in which the filters will be called if a request comes as /XYZ/abc.do and why?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the order their mappings are defined in web.xml

If using annotations (`@WebFilter`) the order [seems to be undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations) - you still have to declare the `<filter-mapping>` entries in web.xml.

Comment: so its F1,F2,F3?What if in case of servlet? lets say  i have 1 pattern matching 2 servlets?

Comment: it doesn't matter how much servlets/uris it matches. The current target resource is only one, and for it, the filters are invoked in the order of the mapping declaration. (So yes - F1,F2,F3)

Comment: yes i got it.But now i am asking abt a totally seperate scenerio where same url patter matches to 2 different servlet s1 and s2.Which servlet will be called?This quesiton  is independent of filters

Comment: if it's independent, ask another question ;) (and mark an answer as accepted on this one)

Comment: ok done............................................... :).Can u comment now?

Comment: by "ask another question" I meant to press the "Ask question" button and formulate the new question

Comment: done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938138/what-if-url-pattern-matches-multiple-servlets

Answer (score 30):

Section 6.2.4 of the [Servlet specification 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/):

> When processing a `<filter-mapping>` element using the `<url-pattern>` style, the container must determine whether the `<url-pattern>` matches the request URI using the path mapping rules defined in Chapter 12, “Mapping Requests to Servlets”.
>
> The order the container uses in building the chain of filters to be applied for a particular request URI is as follows:
>
> 1. First, the `<url-pattern>` matching filter mappings in the same order that these elements appear in the deployment descriptor.
> 2. Next, the `<servlet-name>` matching filter mappings in the same order that these elements appear in the deployment descriptor.
>
> If a filter mapping contains both `<servlet-name>` and `<url-pattern>`, the container must expand the filter mapping into multiple filter mappings (one for each `<servlet-name>` and `<url-pattern>`), preserving the order of the `<servlet-name>` and `<url-pattern>` elements.

In short: they're applied in the order in which they appear in the XML file. It gets interesting if you hit an URL that's covered by both `<url-pattern>` and `<servlet-name>` bound filters, because then all URL-pattern bound filters are applied before all servlet-name bound filters. I've never been in this situation (haven't seen any servlet-name bound filters at all), but I reckon it could be quite confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I had `<url-pattern>` and `<servlet-name>` bound filters in my `web.xml` and was wondering why the URL-pattern bound filter was executed first, even if the servlet-name bound filter was defined first in the XML.