# what if url pattern matches multiple servlets?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name> s1</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern> /abc </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name> s2</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern> /abc </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name> s3</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Which servlet will be called if a request /abc comes?and why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Check this](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html). In short:

- if the mappings have exactly the same pattern, there is no guarantee which servlet one will be invoked. So avoid that.
- If the patterns are overlapping, the most specific one is picked. (`/abc` is more specific than `/*`)

Comment: Nice explanation, and the link provided is awesome, simple to grasp.

Comment: Does the same thing apply for url-patter in filter-mapping ?

Comment: @Bozho the link doesn't work anymore. Here's wayback machine copy https://web.archive.org/web/20160224184048/http://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html