# Force a "WebFilter" to be executed first

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

Consider the following filter mappings in my `web.xml`

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>rememberMeCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>mustBeSignedInFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

As far as I understand from the tests I made, if I go to `/private/account.jsp`, the mustBeSignedInFilter will always be executed first ([from what I could read, it's because the path is more specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938138/what-if-url-pattern-matches-multiple-servlets)). I need the rememberMeCookieFilter to be executed first.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing filter mappings with servlet mappings. All filters matching the URL are executed in the same order as their filter mappings are been specified in `web.xml`. So swap the filter mappings and it'll work as you expected.

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>mustBeSignedInFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>rememberMeCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks Bauke! Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856866/webfilter-doesnt-work-with-ordering-in-web-xml