# Understanding URL pattern matching in servlets and filters

Tags: url, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

I have some doubts in understanding how the value in `<url-pattern`> is interpreted to match in either `<servlet-mapping>` or `<filter-mapping>`. Basically the doubts comes in how `*` is interpreted.

Let us assume that I deployed a web-application(.war) with context root /firstweb.

Consider the following `<url-pattern>` defined in web.xml

(1) `<url-pattern>   /*             </url-pattern>`
(2) `<url-pattern>  /test/abc       </url-pattern>`
(3) `<url-pattern>  /test/abc/*     </url-pattern>`
(4) `<url-pattern>  /*/abc          </url-pattern>`

What I am aware of is that `"*"` matches any string / text. With this as basis, I have some doubts.

Q1) For case (1) viz `/*` would it match anything? If so, would this match `/test`, `/text/abc`, `/test/abc` etc. when it is in the url?

Q2) Now for case (2) viz `/test/abc` would it match when url is exactly `/test/abc`? what about `/*` because as I believe `*` means any text. Won't this make it ambiguous matching pattern?

Q3) Also, I believe all these url are w.r.t to context-root i.e. all urls are like: `/firstweb/xxx' ,`/firstweb/test/abc`,`/firstweb/`.

Any answers in simple words to clear this doubt is highly appreciated.

**Edit**

Did some more research, the following links are helpful in understanding the how to interpret `<url-pattern>`

a) [what if url pattern matches multiple servlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938138/what-if-url-pattern-matches-multiple-servlets)

b) http://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html

Comment: Asking one question per Question makes it easier to find duplicates. Each of those questions are already individually asked before. Hint: browse through "Related" list on right hand side.

Comment: @BalusC: I agree, however sometimes questions are interrelated that it is imperative to put them as a single place. I looked at the links,  my doubts are still not clear. If you can answer for (1) and (2) would be great. Personally I checked in tomcat for * and /test/abc and it seems * can take any input urls /test /text /test/abc/xyz ...

Comment: 1) is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4140448 2) is indirectly answered by answer to 1).

Comment: Thanks for this link, had seen this.. let me check this again.. Thanks lots!