# Tomcat: using servlet and websocket (jsr356) in same web app

Tags: tomcat, servlets, websocket, guice-servlet, jsr356

I create a sample webapp using Guice-servlets and websocket in tomcat, now once guice filter is used websocket stop working

### Basic information:

In my web.xml, i initialized the Guiceservlet using `GuiceBasedListener`

```
<web-app>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>test.GuiceBasedListener</listener-class>
    </listener>          
    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`GuieBasedListener` Code which binds all request `/*` to `MyDispatcher`

```
public class GuiceBasedListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector( new ServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                bind(MyDispatcher.class).asEagerSingleton();
                serve("/*").with(MyDispatcher.class);//////IMPORTANT LINE//
            }
        });}}
```

`MyDispatcher` code which just respond with a String

```
public class MyDispatcher extends HttpServlet {    
    @Inject private Injector injector;
    public MyDispatcher() {}    
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        resp.getOutputStream().print("SUCCESS:" + req);
    }
}
```

Also i have a @ServerEndPoint for Websocket

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/chat2")
public class WebSocket{
....
    @OnOpen
    public void start(Session session) {        
        System.out.println("Staring:"+this);
   }
....
}
```

**Observations:**

1. Now if i run the app and hit http://app:8080/test it returns `SUCCESS`
2. But if i try to connect to websocket using ws://app:8080/websocket/chat2 it fails
3. Now if i comment `serve("/*").with(MyDispatcher.class);` basically if we switch off guice routing the websocket starts to work
4. If i switch off guice-servlet but add a servlet mapping in web.xml like below websocket still works

   `< servlet-mapping >`
   `< servlet-name > HelloWorld< / servlet-name >`
   `< url-pattern > /* < / url-pattern >`
   `< / servlet-mapping >`

**What am i missing or doing wrongly?**

---

**EDIT:**

**Observation-conti:**

5. What i did was defined a simple filter which just respond with `FILTER` .

`public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.getOutputStream().print("FILTER");    }`

and changed my web.xml to

```
<web-app>           
    <filter>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>test.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>       
</web-app>
```

Now hitting the `http://localhost:8080/app/x` return `FILTER` as expected.
But trying to connect with websocket fail as the request shows something like this. 
I also noticed that as i change the String `MyFilter` return the content length in response changes , which meaning the request reached `MyFilter` before tomcat handled it for websocket.

[image]

6. I changed the web.xml to below and guice and websocket are working fine now.. so i think Guice is not honoring the WsFilter that registered after the GuiceFilter

   ```
   <filter>
   <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping> 

    <filter>
       <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```

---

TOMCAT 8.0, Window 7, Java 1.7 , Guice 4.0, Guice-servlet-4.0

Comment: *"How can i tell tomcat to first consider serverEndPoint url for routing the request before matching the filter url patterns ?"* Frankly, Tomcat already does that. You just misinterpreted the cause of your actual problem. I recommend to rewrite the question to tell in detail about the observed symptoms of the actual problem instead of asking how to solve a misassumed possible cause. I gather that the `GuiceFilter` has just a bug and needs a simple bugfix, but it isn't clear what exactly as long as you don't elaborate about the actually observed symptoms.

Comment: @BalusC you are right ... i have rewritten the issue

Comment: *"But if i try to connect to websocket using ws://app:8080/websocket/chat2 it fails"* How exactly does it fail? What exactly happens and what exactly happens not and what exactly happens instead?

Comment: @BalusC Added an interesting observation

Comment: @BalusC I think the Filters in web.xml are registered before the WsFilter of tomcat. Just a speculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That also looks like a Guice issue to me (as already mentioned in comments). Using servlets and WebSockets in same application should not be a problem, even with a servlet mapping that covers `/*`.

2 relevant things about servlets and filters:

- as already mentioned, when getting a websocket upgrade request (a very special kind of http request), normally Tomcat should not let it go through the filters. It looks like Guice breaks this somehow.
- Filters are applied [in the order their mappings are defined in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938067/6730571).

So, if WsFilter is first, it will intercept the request first, then [check if it's a WebSocket upgrade request](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/TOMCAT_8_0_0/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/server/WsFilter.java#L51).
If it's indeed a WebSocket connection, the filter will *not pass it on to the rest of the chain*.
If it's another type of request (GET, POST...), it will pass it on, and then Guice will do its thing.

(so you found a first solution here)

If Guice filter is first, AND you use `serve("/*")...`, then it breaks your WS.

If you comment out `serve("/*")...`, then it does not matter if Guice filter is first or not, WsFilter can even be absent: your WS can be reached (which establishes GuiceFilter alone is OK).

So Guice has its own "layer of interception" above servlet mappings, and I think that's what breaks WebSockets. I don't know if there is a bug or anything to fix in Guice (I mean probably, but don't know what exactly), but you *can* specify exceptions to Guice (unlike servlet mappings in `web.xml`).
Replace this:

```
serve("/*").with(TestServlet.class);
```

with this:

```
serveRegex("/(?!websocket/).*").with(TestServlet.class);
// Regex that accepts /.* but excludes /websocket/.*
```

With that, you can keep the servlet mapping on `/*`, and remove `WsFilter` as it is not needed. (Tested, works for me)

So that's a second solution, that has the advantage that it also allows to specify exceptions for non-WebSocket stuff.