# Servlet Filtering using java EE 6 annotation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, annotations, servlet-filters

Is it possible to simulate a servlet filter chain using @ApplicationPath and @Path annotations in EE 6?

Example:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
class Filter extends Application { 
    @Path("/*")
    public void filter() {
        log.info("Request to API");
    }
}
```

...

```
@Path("/foo")
class Foo {
    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String bar() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Where the URL would be http://foobar.com/api/foo/bar but the "filter" method would be invoked as if it were a servlet filter chain. I know the approach above wont work but is there an annotated approach in this ilk that would achieve the same as if the "Filter" was configured from web.xml file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JBoss 7 (even JBoss 6 already) supports Java EE 6 which in turn covers Servlet 3.0. Perhaps your `web.xml` is incorrectly been declared conform Servlet 2.5 which caused the `@WebFilter` not to work at all. Ensure that the root declaration of your `web.xml` is been declared conform Servlet 3.0 like follows:

```xml
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

Then you can just use [`@WebFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html):

```
@WebFilter("/api/*")
public class FooFilter implements Filter {

    // ...

}
```

The examples which you've shown there are by the way part of JAX-RS, which is another API (a RESTful webservice API) built on top of Servlets. To learn more about JAX-RS, the [Jersey user guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html) may be useful.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlet-Filters wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Comment: Will this allow me to configure the filters without a web.xml file or can I use annotation only?

Comment: You don't need to specify them by `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` in `web.xml`. But if you already didn't have a `web.xml`, then that's also perfectly fine. The inability to use `@WebFilter` and stating that you're using Servlet 2.5 as you implied yourself however indicates that you *already* have a `web.xml` which in turn is incorrectly been declared conform Servlet 2.5. Or didn't you actually tried anything yourself at all?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what I said!! Yes have tried a fair bit myself - Im porting software from JBoss 6 to Jboss 7. Now back to the question: "...is there an annotated approach in this ilk that would achieve the same as if the "Filter" was configured from web.xml file?". Quite clearly I am looking for a solution that does not require a web.xml file. Thx

Comment: I have already answered that: use `@WebFilter`. Read the docs for all options of the annotation: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html The only which you cannot control is the ordering of the filters. For that you still really need `web.xml`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations/6561816#6561816