# Creating filter's with Jboss 7.1.1 Final (Annotations method)

Tags: jboss7.x, servlet-filters

I'm trying to create an Filter to execute with all (/*) pattern URL's using Jboss 7.1.1 Final + java 7 + javaee 3.0 and it doesnt work. The same code work perfectly running under Tomcat 7.0 server, but no success with Jboss. I've already looked at the Official Documentation of Jboss and nothing about it. Any good soul to help me? These the simple Test filter I'm trying to work:

```
package br.com.xxx.filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;



@WebFilter(filterName = "myFilter",urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class Teste implements Filter {

public Teste() {
}

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
System.out.println("THE IS A SIMPLE TEST!!!!!!!");
chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the dispatcherTypes to see if that forces it? dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD}

Comment: I already tried tthe dispatcherTypes ..  Request , include , forward erros .. all of it...

Comment: It also may require you to register it dynamically with the servlet context.  Good info on that is here: http://blog.eisele.net/2011/06/dynamically-registering-webfilter-with.html  Not sure if this helps until I can try tonight.

Comment: Here's another link that was jboss specific with the registration example: http://www.mastertheboss.com/servlet-30/servlet-30-tutorial (this shows adding servlet, but just use addFilter like in first example)

Comment: I will try right now. back in few with news.

Comment: Last thought, make sure your web.xml has proper root declaration -- Tomcat/JBoss may behave differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146530/servlet-filtering-using-java-ee-6-annotation

Comment: can you be a bit more specific than "it doesn't work". what does happen? how do you test it? with what urls, do you get any response?

Comment: eis , I dont have anny reaction of the filter. The pattern is /* , so , its not relevant mention the URL's Ive tyied. I got any kind of erros, just nothing happens (I dont get the println in my console)

Comment: David Fleeman, Worked!  Tnx for that.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED#
as David Fleeman said :

"It also may require you to register it dynamically with the servlet context. Good info on that is here: blog.eisele.net/2011/06/… Not sure if this helps until I can try tonight. – David Fleeman "

Comment: Glad it worked!  I've recently set up a JBoss AS7 stack, but have not done enough to run into this issue yet myself...