# How to order filters with Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I am creating a Java web project with Spring, maven and Apache Tomcat 7. In this project I have a web.xml like this:

```xml
<display-name>web</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Servlet de Spring. Definimos el Servlet que recibirá todas las peticiones que 
    se realizen a la página -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param> -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<absolute-ordering>
    <name>encodingFilter</name>
    <name>cors</name>
    <name>springSecurityFilterChain</name>
    <name>FileUploadFilter</name>
</absolute-ordering>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.SimpleCorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

When I start Tomcat the following messages appears on the console:

```
org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml orderWebFragments
Used a wrong fragment name encodingFilter at web.xml absolute-ordering tag!
org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml orderWebFragments
Used a wrong fragment name cors at web.xml absolute-ordering tag! 
org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml orderWebFragments
Used a wrong fragment name springSecurityFilterChain at web.xml absolute-ordering tag!
```

I have tried the same with Apache Tomcat 6 and I haven't had any problem. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you can define the order for **servlet filters**. See the following posts here on SO

1. [<absolute-ordering> is not working in tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882711/absolute-ordering-is-not-working-in-tomcat-7)
2. [Servlet filters' order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086712/servlet-filters-order-of-execution)
3. [How to define servlet filter order of execution using annotations in WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have checked the links that you have post and I think that I can't implement the solutions of the fisrt and last link because I can't modify the filters web-fragments of Spring for establish a order. I'll try the second option