# @WebFilter define order

Tags: tomcat, servlet-filters

I have e.g. 2 Filters (one to check if the user is logged in, and one to check further persmissions), both defined by the Annotation **@WebFilter("/pages/*");**

Now I want that first the loginFilter is checked and only if it succeeds the second filter.

How can i specify the filter order?

thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define Servlet filter order of execution using annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations)

Comment: Note: this has nothing to do with JSF (filters are not sitting in `javax.faces` package at all). Also please read tag descriptions before adding tags; the `[filter]` tag description clearly says to use `[servlet-filters]` instead of it's about servlet filters.