# Order of execution of servlet filer and jax-rs filter

Tags: jax-rs, servlet-filters

My application has both simple servlet filters (defined in web.xml), and a jax-rs filter annotated with @Provider. I notice for now that the jax-rs filter gets executed after the servlet filters. How and where should this ordering or chaining be defined? and how is the ordering currently determined?

Comment: Sounds like you have to use web.xml to control order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations-in-war

Comment: Are you asking how to make servlet-level filters execute _after_ jersey-level filters or are you asking how to order groups of servlet filters independent of jersey filters and vice versa?

Comment: how do i made servlet level filters execute after jersey filters? I do not define my jersey filters in web.xml, as i use the @Provider annotation... Do I need to define them in web.xml?

Comment: How to order the filters in such a way that the jersey filter is executed before the servlet filter? Does `<load-on-startup>` help this case?