# Is there any way to specify the order of a filter outside of declaring it in web.xml?

Tags: java, web.xml, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

As of Servlet 3.0, we can now declare web filters by annotation ([@WebFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html))or dynamically (via the [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) object).

I know that using the @WebFilter does not allow for specifying the filter order.  Similarly I haven't found any way to specify the order when declaring it dynamically via the [ServletContext.addFilter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addFilter-java.lang.String-javax.servlet.Filter-) method.  I've looked at the FilterRegistration object, but there is nothing there either.

Does that mean that the only way to specify the order of a filter in the filter chain is via web.xml?  Is there no other mechanism available?  Is this not a significant oversight of Servlet 3.0+?

Where in the chain do filters declared via annotation or via the ServletContext object?  At the end of those declared in web.xml?  Undefined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Does that mean that the only way to specify the order of a filter in the filter chain is via web.xml?*

Yes. Check the following sections of the [Servlet 3.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf):

- 4.4.2 Programmatically adding and configuring Filters
- 6.2.4 Configuration of Filters in a Web Application
- 8.1.2 @WebFilter

The only place where filter ordering is mentioned is in section 6.2.4, which specifies how to do it with **web.xml**. Ordering is not mentioned in the sections on **addFilter()** and **@WebFilter**.

> *Is there no other mechanism available?*

Not in the Servlet 3.0 specification, so no.

> *Is this not a significant oversight of Servlet 3.0+?*

I doubt that the omission is an "oversight". A comment from BalusC is this [relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations-in-war) offers one plausible reason why there is no alternative mechanism: *What if your webapp ships with 3rd party libraries which includes a filter? It's hard to tell its order beforehand.*

> *Where in the chain do filters declared via annotation or via the ServletContext object? At the end of those declared in web.xml?
>   Undefined?*

The ordering is necessarily undefined since the spec does not address those scenarios.

Comment: I think it would be better if developer can add a priority count.  And if two priority is equal then the filter name's order decide the right order