# Can you build a FilterChain with annotations?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlet-filters

It is my understanding that to build a `FilterChain` more than one filter deep, I have to mention the filters in the `web.xml` in order.

But then what's the point in having all these fancy annotations if I cannot use them because I need to specify things in the xml anyway?

Can I somehow build a `FilterChain` from annotations?

Comment: This might probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations-in-war

Comment: @Frito it does, thank you. Would you like to make an answer out of it?