# Filter order in `web.xml` ignored when using annotations?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

Simple filter chain (full code at the bottom of the post).

Let's say I have a login page that provides username and password.

Request passes through an authentication filter that checks the credentials and if it checks out, adds a user object as an attribute to the request.

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter",urlPatterns = "/secret")
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {...}
```

Then the request passes through a warning filter that will take that attribute and use it to log that the user accessed the component.

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityWarningFilter",urlPatterns = "/secret")
public class SecurityWarningFilter implements Filter { ... }
```

I've now been trying to force an NPE by deliberately wiring them in the wrong order. So the `SecurityWarningFilter` should handle the request first, try to operate on the attribute that is not yet there and throw an exception.

I've taken a look at [How to define servlet filter order of execution using annotations in WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations-in-war) and since

> The filters are invoked in the order in which filter mappings appear in the filter mapping list of a WAR. ~[Servlet Tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/servlets006.html)

this is what I punched into the `web.xml`:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityWarningFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern />
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern />
</filter-mapping>
```

This doesn't do anything, though. The `AuthFilter`still handles the request first and only if it passes it on to the chain does the `SecurityWarningFilter` get to do its thing.

Why is that? And how do I force the NPE?

Note that if I comment out the annotations and instead go for the full xml definition:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>[...].webapp.filters.AuthFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityWarningFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>[...].webapp.filters.SecurityWarningFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityWarningFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secret</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secret</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

THEN I get the NPE I'm looking for. (And flipping the order in which I define the `<filter-mapping>` tags gets rid of it again.)
But I'd very much prefer to use annotations for the filter definitions, instead of `<filter>` tags.

I'm using `Apache Tomcat/7.0.47`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Also, Merry Christmas to all of you.)

***UPDATE***
It seems that if I mention the url patterns in the xml, I can force the NPE when using annotations:

```
<web-app
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0" metadata-complete="false"
>
    <!-- this mapping forces an NPE -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SecurityWarningFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/secret</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/secret</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- other servlets here -->
</web-app>
```

which indicates to me that there's something about the `<url-pattern />` that needs some configuring -- so it takes the url patterns from the annotations -- that I haven't done just yet.

Any ideas?

code:

**login.jsp**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action='/webapp/secret' method='post'>
        username: <input type='text' name ='username'><br>
        password: <input type='password' name ='password'><br>
        <input type='submit', value='login'>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Webapp</display-name> 
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SecurityWarningFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern />
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern />
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- other servlets here -->
</web-app>
```

***EDIT***: as per Steve's suggestion (thank you), this has been updated to

new **web.xml**

```
<web-app
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0" metadata-complete="false"
>
    <!-- this mapping forces an NPE -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SecurityWarningFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern />
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern />
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- other servlets here -->
</web-app>
```

**AuthFilter.java**

```
package [...].webapp.filters;

import [...].security.Credentials;
import [...].webapp.consts.AuthConstants;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@WebFilter(filterName = "AuthFilter",urlPatterns = "/secret")
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String username = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");

        if(username == null || password == null){
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.println("access denied");
            return;
        }

        Credentials creds = new Credentials(username,password, false);
        if(validate(creds)){
            req.setAttribute(AuthConstants.ATTR_ACTIVE_USER,creds);
            chain.doFilter(req,resp);
        } else{
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.println("username or pasword is incorrect");
        }
    }

    private boolean validate(Credentials creds){
        Set<Credentials> acceptedUsers = getAcceptedUsers();
        return acceptedUsers.contains(creds);
    }

    private Set<Credentials> getAcceptedUsers(){
        //imagine a proper fetch, e.g. from DB or some cache, here
        return new HashSet<Credentials>(){{add(new Credentials("foo","bar", false));}};
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

**SecurityWarningFilter.java**

```
package [...].webapp.filters;

import [...].security.Credentials;
import [...].webapp.consts.AuthConstants;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityWarningFilter",urlPatterns = "/secret")
public class SecurityWarningFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Credentials accessingUser = (Credentials)req.getAttribute(AuthConstants.ATTR_ACTIVE_USER);
        doSecurityWarning(accessingUser);
        chain.doFilter(req,resp);
    }

    private void doSecurityWarning(Credentials accessingUser) {
        String timestamp = new Date().toString();

        //imagine some proper logging, here
        System.err.println(String.format("WARNING[%s] access to secured resource by user '%s'",timestamp,accessingUser.username));
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

**SecretServlet.java**

```
package [...].webapp.servlets;

import [...].security.Credentials;
import [...].webapp.consts.AuthConstants;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/secret")
public class SecretServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        serveRequest(req,resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        serveRequest(req, resp);
    }

    private void serveRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Credentials authorisedUser = (Credentials)req.getAttribute(AuthConstants.ATTR_ACTIVE_USER);
        resp.getWriter().println(String.format("You are authorised. Welcome %s.",authorisedUser.username));
    }
}
```

**Credentials.java**

```
package [...].security;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.HexBinaryAdapter;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Credentials{
    public final String username;
    final String password;

    public Credentials(String username, String password, boolean isPasswordHashed) {
        this.username = username;

        if(isPasswordHashed) this.password = password;
        else {
            MessageDigest md;
            try {
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }

            md.update(password.getBytes());
            byte[] hash = md.digest();

            this.password = (new HexBinaryAdapter()).marshal(hash);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null) return false;
        if(!(obj instanceof Credentials)) return false;
        Credentials other = (Credentials)obj;
        return this.username.equals(other.username) && this.password.equals(other.password);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(username,password);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[\n\t%s\n\t%s\n]", username,password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible to achieve what you want under any of the servlet specifications (up to 4.0).

The XSD for the `filter-mapping` element contains the following:

```
  <xsd:choice minOccurs="1"
              maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element name="url-pattern"
                 type="javaee:url-patternType"/>
    <xsd:element name="servlet-name"
                 type="javaee:servlet-nameType"/>
  </xsd:choice>
```

This indicates that a filter-mapping must contain at least one of either a `url-pattern` or a `servlet-name`.

Furthermore, this:

```
  <url-pattern />
```

is the equivalent of:

```
  <url-pattern></url-pattern>
```

The specifications (§12.2) state that:

> The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>   application's context root...

In other words `<url-pattern />` will always override any patterns that you have declared in your `@WebFilter` annotations because XML declarations **always** supersede annotations.

Therefore, if you need specific filter ordering then you must declare the complete `filter-mapping` elements including the correct `url-pattern` elements in the required order within the web.xml.

Incidentally, the header of your web.xml deployment descriptor is for a much older version of the servlet specification.

For Tomcat 7.x it needs to be:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0" metadata-complete="false" >
```

`metadata-complete="false"` is actually the default.

Comment: There's no trusting maven archetypes, anymore.
Anyway, I did exchange the header and it didn't do anything, I'm afraid.

Comment: I wish you had just made a new answer than edited your old one. I only noticed you edited it when I came back to offer a bounty for an answer. :P If you had made a new reply, I would've gotten a notification. At any rate, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sorry - I was wondering what kind of notifications that you would get. Now I know!