# Spring DelegatingFilterProxy execution order issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I have web.xml defined in following way

```
 <filter>
   <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
   </filter-class>
 </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>



 <filter>
   <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
   </filter-class>
 </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/filter2.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:filter1-beans-def.xml
            classpath:filter2-bean-def.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

      //dispatcher Servlet defination
```

from above sequence filter1 defination comes first and then second filter. Same in the case for defining its respective beans in context.

But actually my filter executed in this order : **filter 2 ---> filter 1**.
I want to execute them in reverse order?

What wrong is happening here? Thank you

Comment: It has nothing to do with spring nor with spring-mvc. As your filters are defined in a web.xml file, it is processed by the servlet container, and spec requires that the container apply *<url-pattern> matching filter mappings in the same order that these
elements appear in the deployment descriptor*. How are you sure of the order ?

Comment: Yes I am sure because I have set debugger points

Comment: What it you servlet container? It looks like it does not respect specifications...

Comment: Where have you placed debugger points? Are you actually sure the `DelegatingFilterProxy` is being used? Your filter doesn't have, by any change a `@WebFilter` annotation? Or there is a `web-fragment.xml` somewhere of `ServletContainerInitializer` or `WebApplicationInitializer` messing around with the filters? So please add your full `web.xml` and your actual filters (at least the class definition with annotation present).

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the documentation I've read, the filters should be executed in the order the filter-mapping elements are defined.

[How do web.xml filters work? Can you have two filters map to all pages (/*) and specify the order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122455/how-do-web-xml-filters-work-can-you-have-two-filters-map-to-all-pages-and)

> The order in which filters are invoked is the order in which
>   filter-mapping declarations that match a request URI for a servlet
>   appear in the list of filter-mapping elements

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

> The order of the filters in the chain is the same as the order in
>   which filter mappings appear in the web application deployment
>   descriptor.

One thing to try would be to rearrange your filter and filter-mapping elements to be grouped together:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
   <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/filter2.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```